# Is it possible to colocate two pods with the same index but belonging to two different statefulsets on the same node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

For two Statefulsets `sts1` and `sts2`, would it be possible to schedule:

- sts1-pod-0 and sts2-pod-0 on the same node,
- sts1-pod-1 and sts2-pod-1 on the same node,
- ...
- sts1-pod-n and sts2-pod-n on the same node,

An in addition do not collocate two pods of a given Statefulset on the same node?

Answer (score 1):

```
sts1-pod-0 and sts2-pod-0 on the same node,
sts1-pod-1 and sts2-pod-1 on the same node,
...
sts1-pod-n and sts2-pod-n on the same node,
```

One possible way is run the paired containers in the same StatefulSet, this has the same effect as running side by side as pod on the same node. In this case your affinity rule only need to ensure no two pods run on same node.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I was aware of this possibility because that is what I have currently, but is there something else? We investigate to improve our application design, and splitting our paired containers pods in two pods looks like a possible track to us, if it is made possible by k8s scheduler.